# Debugging Chrome which is crashing on a webpage I built

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, crash

I've trying to figure out how to debug Chrome which keeps crashing every couple of hours.

Error Code: `Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT`

The app I built is sort of a sales dashboard that is hooked up to a NodeJS backend and has live updating.

I've navigated over to `chrome://crashes/` and found the file but it doesn't seem to be readable. The file extension is `.DMP`.

I've also taken a look at the Chrome crash page [Troubleshoot Chrome crashes](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271277?hl=en#troubleshoot) (the crash I'm seeing is the `Aw, Snap! error message`), added the `--enable-logging --v=1` to a testing profile and then went to the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\chrome_debug.log` file.

There's a ton of information there, can anyone send in the correct direction or perhaps give me some tips here?

TIA